# GNU Octave Save entire workspace

Tags: octave

I can save individual variables fine in Octave, but i'm stuck when it comes to saving the entire workspace (ie, the whole screen with everything I've written on it)

eg

save file1
load file1

Doesn't seem to do anything

Any help greatly appreciated

David B

Answer (score 0):

I do not think what you describe is a feature within Octave. You can save variables and the command history, see the description linked below, but I don't think its possible to save "the whole screen with everything I've written on it". Maybe if you better describe what elements you'd like to recover, specific instructions could be given.

Note that you aren't creating a "math document" like in Mathematica or GNU Maxima. This is a command interpreter, and recording commands entered and variables used is the usual extent of things to save.

https://phoxis.org/2013/04/06/save-work-environment-in-octave/

Comment: there _is_ the `diary` command. well done for figuring out what OP wanted though, I had no idea what he was on about the way he asked.

Comment: from the sound of it, he may even be looking for something like the `publish` command

Comment: Thanks for clarifying Nick J :)